# How to represent a multiple choice attribute in UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm modelling a Filter class that stores the options for filtering a search. Some of the attributes are multiple choice.

For example, if you are filtering hotel rooms you have a Price attribute that can take these three values: Best, Average, High. You can choose many values at the same time. In an UI would be represented as a group of checkboxes.

Can this be represented in a UML class diagram?

Comment: Actually, you have three boolean attributes: BestPrice, AveragePrice and HighPrice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)**

[image]

**(2)**

[image]

**(3)**

?

See also: [uml-diagrams.org: Class and Object Diagrams Overview](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html)

---

As @robert-harvey pointed out, your requirement to select many values at the same time is *strange* as you can see from the model